# Whats the rationale for using taylor series in economics?

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, production-function

I've been reading about the translog production function and know its really just a log-log production function approximated using a first order maclauren series.

Why not just leave the function as is? What economic interpretation or use does taking taylor series do for us?

Answer (score 2):

You will gain in flexibility and generality by adding more terms and avoid to impose restrictions on substitution between inputs and returns to scale, that are usually rejected (when tested).